# Bitbucket API bad request while trying to merge

Tags: php, git, curl, bitbucket, bitbucket-api

This is my code:

```
$url = "https://bitbucket.org/api/2.0/repositories/***/***/pullrequests/35/merge";

$curl1 = curl_init();   

curl_setopt($curl1, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC ); 
curl_setopt($curl1, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "***:***");
curl_setopt($curl1, CURLOPT_HEADER, true); 
curl_setopt($curl1, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($curl1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl1, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl1, CURLOPT_POST, true);

echo curl_exec($curl1);
```

Thats the response:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 BAD REQUEST Server: nginx/1.5.10 Date: Wed, 04 Mar 2015 06:03:15 GMT Content-Type: text/plain Content-Length: 11 Connection: keep-alive X-Served-By: app19 X-Render-Time: 0.0410010814667 Content-Language: de X-Static-Version: 572a80470390 Vary: Authorization, Accept-Language, Cookie X-Version: 1d224fb664b6 ETag: "825644f747baab2c00e420dbbc39e4b3" X-Request-Count: 27 X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN Bad Request
```

Why does this not work? (For safety reasons i replaced some informations with ***)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the mandatory parameters for that particular endpoint which should be included in your request body.

According to the [API](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/pullrequests+Resource#pullrequestsResource-Acceptandmergeapullrequest), those mandatory parameters are `owner`, `repo_slug` and `pull_request_id`.

```
$request_body = array(
  'owner'           => 'account-name',
  'repo_slug'       => 'repo-name',
  'pull_request_id' => 35
);
```

Because you specified `application/json` as your Content-Type, you need to `json_encode` the array from above:

```
curl_setopt($curl1, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($request_body));
```

As a side note, you could use [bitbucket-api](https://packagist.org/packages/gentle/bitbucket-api) library, which can help you to interact with Bitbucket API in a [more easy way](http://gentlero.bitbucket.org/bitbucket-api/examples/repositories/pull-requests.html#accept-and-merge-a-pull-request:-(api-2.0)).

Accepting a pull request using that library, looks something like this:

```
$pull = new Bitbucket\API\Repositories\PullRequests();

// set your login credentials here
$pull->getClient()->addListener(
  new \Bitbucket\API\Http\Listener\BasicAuthListener('username', 'password')
);
$pull->accept($account_name, $repo_slug, 35);
```

You can read more in the [docs](http://gentlero.bitbucket.org/bitbucket-api/).

*Disclaimer: I am the author of bitbucket-api library.*