# Error while trying to merge a pullrequest with bitbucket api

Tags: php, git, curl, bitbucket, bitbucket-api

I get an error every time when I'm trying to merge a pull request with the bitbucket api.

This is my code:

```
define('USERNAME','***');
define('PASSWORD','***');

$url = "https://bitbucket.org/api/2.0/repositories/{owner}/{repo}/pullrequests/46/merge";

$curl1 = curl_init();   

curl_setopt($curl1, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC ); 
curl_setopt($curl1, CURLOPT_USERPWD, USERNAME . ":" . PASSWORD);
curl_setopt($curl1, CURLOPT_HEADER, true); 
curl_setopt($curl1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl1, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl1, CURLOPT_POST, true);

echo curl_exec($curl1);
```

And this is the error code:

```
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue HTTP/1.1 400 BAD REQUEST Server: nginx/1.6.2 Date: Wed, 20 May 2015 15:43:27 GMT Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 Content-Length: 113 Connection: keep-alive X-Render-Time: 0.218739032745 Content-Language: de ETag: "2f0273bc2b819d7505bc14bf84d7e129" X-Request-Count: 227 X-Served-By: app19 Vary: Authorization, Accept-Language, Cookie X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN X-Static-Version: 3b0c7aec39d3 X-Version: c288eef4a422 {"error": {"message": "'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\\xe4' in position 11: ordinal not in range(128)"}}
```

I've already tried to send the informations (owner, repo and request id) with "CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS". But I got the same error.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bitbucket API bad request while trying to merge](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28847704/bitbucket-api-bad-request-while-trying-to-merge)

Comment: Nope. Now I get a different error to my first post.